# Can there be non trivial self-dual 5-forms on a 10-dimensional compact orientable manifold without boundary?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

I am puzzled about the following.

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact, orientable Riemannian manifold without boundary. We define the usual inner product $(,)$ for two r-forms $\alpha,\beta\in\Omega^r(M)$ by the formula
$$
(\alpha,\beta) = \int_M \alpha\wedge \star\beta\, .
$$
This inner product is positive-definite, i.e. for any $\alpha\in\Omega^r(M)$, we have
$$
(\alpha.\alpha)\geq 0\, ,
$$
and $(\alpha,\alpha)=0$ if and only if $\alpha =0$.

For definiteness I focus now on a ten-dimensional manifold: dim $M$=10.

Let us consider $\gamma$ a self-dual 5-form, i.e. $-i \gamma = \star \gamma$ (I am using the convention where when acting on a r-form, $\star^2=(-1)^{r(m-r)}$ for dim $M$=m. Moreover, I could have considered anti-self-dual forms, by replacing $-i$ by $i$ in $-i \gamma = \star \gamma$). Then we have

$$
\gamma \wedge \star \gamma = - \gamma \wedge \star \gamma = 0\, ,
$$
where I used the self-duality condition as well as the fact that for a $r$-form $\omega$ and a $p$-form $\eta$, we have $\omega \wedge \eta = (-1)^{rp}\eta\wedge \omega$. But then we have $(\gamma,\gamma)=0$ and thus $\gamma=0$.

My question is: is there a flaw in the above argument?

My puzzle originally comes from the fact that in physics, we often encounter non-trivial 5-forms on 10-dimensional Riemannian manifold. The example that I have in mind is a case where the manifold is not compact ($AdS_5\times S^5$), so strictly speaking there is no contradiction with the above argument. But as far as I can see, the compactness is only necessary to define the integral of the inner product. But in the present case the product $(\gamma,\gamma)=0$, so there is no integration problem (there is no convergence problem).

I admit that the last argument is very hand-waving so I guess this is the place where a there's flaw but I'd like to know what you think.

Thank you for you answer(s).

Edit: Let me add one comment that might sharpen my puzzle.

In the example I have in mind, where $F\in\Omega^5(AdS_5 \times S^5)$ is such that $\star F = -iF$, we have moreover that
$$
\int_{S^5} F
$$
exist. Moreover, it is independent of the radial coordinate (if using the Poincaré coordinates of $AdS_5$). This suggests that there is really nothing wrong with $F$ at infinity, hence the above integrals for the inner product $(,)$ still make sense for this 5-form.

Comment: Is this *really* how differential forms' inner product is defined?  Shouldn't the inner product of two forms be local?  Using an integral to define it makes the inner product only a non-local quantity, does it not?

Comment: I don't understand why this matters. Call it "non-local inner product" if you wish. The argument stays the same. Moreover, I am using a quite standard definition (see e.g. Nakahara, "Topology, Geometry and Physics").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the real and complex as well as Riemannian and pseudo-Riemannian.

Let $X$ be a $2n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Then a self-dual $n$-form is a $+1$-eigenvector of the Hodge star map
$$\star: \Omega^n(X; \Bbb R) \longrightarrow \Omega^n(X; \Bbb R).$$
We have the well-known formula
$$\star^2 = (-1)^{n(2n - n)} \mathrm{Id} = (-1)^{n^2} \mathrm{Id}.$$
Now if $n$ is odd, as it is in your case, Then $\star^2 = -\mathrm{Id}$, so it cannot have $\pm 1$ as eigenvalues, and hence there are no self-dual or anti-self-dual $n$-forms. $\star$ does, however, have $\pm i$ as eigenvalues in this case, so you can define (anti-)self-dual $n$-forms as $\pm i$-eigenvectors of $\star$, as you did in your original post. Notice, however, that when you do this you are now working with *complex* $n$-forms and you should not be using the real inner product any longer.

To complicate matters further, you're really interested in Lorentzian manifolds. One way to define the Hodge star is by
$$\alpha \wedge \star \beta = \langle\alpha, \beta\rangle\, \mathrm{vol},$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product *induced by the metric* $g$. This is the same inner product you integrate to get the global inner product, and when $X$ is a Lorentzian manifold, $g$ is indefinite and hence the inner product on forms is indefinite as well. As you know, there is nothing wrong with having vectors of length zero in an indefinite inner product space (*e.g.* lightlike vectors in Minkowski space).

As a final remark, on a $2n$-dimensional Lorentzian manifold, we actually have
$$\star^2 = (-1)^{n(2n - n) + (2n - 1)}\mathrm{Id} = (-1)^{n^2 + 2n - 1}\mathrm{Id}$$
(the signature of the metric affects things now). When $n$ is odd (as in your $10$-dimensional case), we then see that $\star^2 = \mathrm{Id}$ on a Lorentzian manifold (of dimension $4k + 2$), so we actually use the usual definition of self-duality (without any $i$'s). When $n$ is even (*e.g.* in Minkowski space), then $\star^2 = -\mathrm{Id}$ and we have to use the alternate definition of self-duality and work with complex inner product spaces.

Comment: I wonder, though: the crux of Bru's argument relied on the commutativity of the wedge product.  Does the change in metric signature (from Riemannian to Lorentzian, say) affect the exponent of $(-1)$ in the formula for commuting factors in a wedge product?

Comment: @Muphrid: No, the wedge product is metric-independent. But the Hodge star _does_ depend on the metric. In dimension $4k + 2$ with a positive-definite metric, $\star$ has no real eigenvectors so the argument produces no contradiction. If you consider the $\pm i$-eigenvectors, then you can get norm zero forms, but that's because you're in a complex vector space and not using a sesquilinear form. In dimension $4k+2$ with a Lorentzian metric, there are $\pm 1$-eigenvectors of $\star$ but now the metric is indefinite, so there can be norm zero forms. There is no contradiction in any case.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton: This is what I suspected. Then what I would like to know is the following: what become of the Hodge decomposition theorem and the isomorphism between harmonic $r$-forms and the $r$th de Rham cohomology space?
Because the only proofs I know relies on the positivity of the inner product. I guess the theorems breakdown, but I'd like to be sure.
Maybe I should ask this as a separate question (tell me what do you think).

Comment: Hodge decomposition fails miserably for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. For example on the torus $T^2$ with the Lorentzian metric $dx^2 - dy^2$, the functions $f_k(x, y) = \sin(kx)\sin(ky)$ are harmonic and linearly independent for all $k$. But $H^0(T^2; \Bbb R) \cong \Bbb R$, so clearly harmonic forms can't correspond the cohomology classes. Note that for a Riemannian metric the Laplacian is elliptic, but in the Lorentzian case it is hyperbolic. The full proof of Hodge's theorem relies on the fact that the Laplacian is elliptic for a Riemannian manifold (_i.e._ the metric is positive definite).

Answer (score 0):

Quick summary: Nothing in your question seems to depend on dimension 10; looking at dimension 2 suggests that your problem formulation is suspect.

Let's look at a much simpler situation: the torus, with angular coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$. In this case, $d\theta \wedge d\phi$ is the area-form, and clearly has nonzero integral. It's been a long time since I studied this stuff, but I believe that in this case, we have something like $\star d\theta = i d\phi$ and $\star d\phi = i d\theta$, so that $\star^2 = -1$ as expected by your formula.

Now every form can be written as a sum of a self-dual and an anti-self-dual form: you just compute $s = \frac{1}{2}(\omega - i \star \omega)$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}(\omega + i \star \omega)$, sort of like splitting a matrix into a sum of a symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix. Doing this for $\omega = d\theta$ (and dropping the 1/2), we get the self-dual form

$\sigma = d\theta + d\phi$

That's clearly a nontrivial self-dual 1-form on the torus. But if you evaluate $(\sigma, \sigma)$, you evidently get zero. So your claim about the positive-definiteness of the inner product seems suspect.

Assuming that you can fix up that bit, I suspect that taking the 10-manifold M to be a cartesian product of 5 copiss of the torus, and taking $\omega = \sigma_1 + \ldots + \sigma_5$, where $\sigma_i$ is the form above, on the $i$th torus, will give you the thing you are looking for.

Comment: By definition, the action of $\star$ is $\star(d x^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge d x^{i_r})=\frac{\sqrt g}{(m-r)!}\epsilon^{i_1\cdots i_r}_{\phantom{i_1\cdots i_r}j_1\cdots j_{m-r}} d x^{j_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge d x^{j_{m-r}}$, so I don't see where you get the factor of $i$ in $\star d \theta = id \phi$. I get $\star d \theta = d\phi$ and $\star d  \phi = - d \theta$ and thus your $\sigma$ is not self-dual.

Comment: @Bru you wrote $i$ in your definition of self-dual. What is the significance of that $i$?

Comment: Yep. I screwed up. (The last time I thought about Hodge-star was about 25 years ago!) My formula for splitting a form should have been $s = \frac{1}{2} (\omega + \star \omega)$ and $a = \frac{1}{2} (\omega - \star \omega)$. That means that for $\omega = d\theta$, ignoring the 1/2, I get $\sigma = d\theta - d\phi$. That form is self-dual, in the sense that $\star \sigma = \sigma$. (This doesn't match your definition of self-dual, which has an extra $i$ in it, so maybe I'm still screwed up).    My remaining comments stand: it's self-dual, but $(\sigma, \sigma)=0$. Something's broken somewhere.

Comment: @Muphrid: This might also be the origin of the puzzle, but I am not sure. In fact originally I am doing pseudo-Riemannian geometry, where obviously the inner product is no positive-definite. The factor of i comes from analytic continuation, so I am extending everything to complex numbers. But then surely a statement like positive-definiteness is meaningless... have to think about is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the case of using complex numbers as the base field.  Using the reals only, I believe that in a space of dimensionality $2n$, there are self-dual $n$-vectors and $n$-forms only when $n$ is itself even.

This can be seen in your formula $\gamma \wedge \gamma = (-1)^{n^2} \gamma \wedge \gamma$.  If $n$ is even, then you just get $\gamma \wedge \gamma = \gamma \wedge \gamma$, a true statement.  This makes sense; in 4d spacetime, there are self-dual 2-vectors (some EM-fields, for instance).  I won't consider this a proof that such dual $n$-vectors and $n$-forms exist; merely, they are not ruled out using this argument.

If $n$ is odd, then your argument $\gamma \wedge \gamma = - \gamma \wedge \gamma$ holds, and thus in 10d we see that there are no self-dual 5-vectors.  For the same reason, there can be no self-dual 1-vectors in a 2d space (as John pointed out).